# Simplify function to sum the absolute value of the difference between all pairs of elements of a sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity

Given a sorted array of *N* elements, I need to find the absolute sum of the differences of all elements.

Given 4 elements (1, 2, 3 and 4):

> |1-2|+|1-3|+|1-4|+|2-3|+|2-4|+|3-4| = 10

Here is my code in Java:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //just for understanding , the Array List is already filled with numbers 
public static int lsum(int N)
{
    int sum =0;

    for( int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        int w =a.get(i);
        for(int j =i;j<N;j++)
        {
            int z = a.get(j);
            sum =sum +(z-w);
        }

        }
    return(sum);

}
```

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm rather than the trivial one I am using (O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity). This is a requirement for a bigger program which requires this function. The input (number of elements) can be as big as 10<sup>5</sup>.

Comment: 1. What is `min`? 2. Don't you need `abs` somewhere? 3. Do we know anything about the numbers in the array (i.e., their span, distribution,...)? 4. Setting `j=i+1` instead of `j=i` will save you `N` steps.

Comment: @VedranŠego 1. corrected. 2. Consider the list to be sorted in ascending order. 3. k< 10^5 that is all that's given. 4. Thanks for the save, however when the input size is considered the (10^5) does not really help in reducing O(n^2) complexity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see this mathematically. I am assuming that `a` is an ascendingly sorted array. I start with indexes from 1, to get better readability (by avoiding `n-1` as often as possible).

We want the following sum:

$$\begin{array}{l@{}l@{}l@{}l}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (a_j - a_i) = (a_2 - a_1) &+ (a_3 - a_1) &+ (a_4 - a_1) + & \dots + (a_n - a_1) +\\
                    &+ (a_3 - a_2) &+ (a_4 - a_2) + & \dots + (a_n - a_2) +\\
                                &&+ (a_4 - a_3) + & \dots + (a_n - a_3) +\\
                                            &&& \dots
\end{array}$$

So, we:

1. add `a1` zero times, `a2` once,... `ak` k-1 times, and
2. subtract `a1` n-1 times, `a2` n-2 times,... `ak` n-k times.

I'd say that your sum is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)a_k - \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)a_k = \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-n-1)a_k
$$

Given your example (1,2,3,4), we get:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^4 (2k-4-1)a_k = -3 \cdot 1 + (-1 \cdot 2) + 1 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 4 = -3 - 2 + 3 + 12 = 10.
$$

This has a linear complexity, which is optimal, because you need to "visit" each member of the array at least once (which is linear).

I believe you can write your code by yourself. Just set indexes to go from zero, but be careful about the formula: `2k - n - 1` becomes `2k - n + 1` when `k` starts from zero.

Comment: woah! Thanks a lot. The break up of the formula did the trick.

Comment: What should I say? excellent!

Answer (score 0):

I would not give you the exact solution to this problem rather I would help you to get an intuition on how to solve this question.

If we try to generalize count of the number of times a particular number at index *i* is getting added and the number of times it is being subtracted then for every index *i* we can use that mathematically derived formula to compute the sum of contributions of every number in the absolute difference in **O(N) time and O(1) extra space**.

You can refer to this video if you still find difficulties in understanding this concept.

Video Link:-

https://youtu.be/A4sz4kNDa-8

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vaibhav! And welcome to Stack Exchange. But let's not open ~7 years old threads, unless the question is unanswered or you have something more valuable to add to which is missing. Might I suggest to re-read answering guide. Cheers. :)